# Jetty threads getting blocked and dead locked

Tags: clojure, jetty, embedded-jetty, ring, http-kit

I am using jetty "7.6.8.v20121106" as a part of https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/tree/master/ring-jetty-adapter with my server.

I am making calls using http://http-kit.org/ with following code. Essentially I am making server calls but ignoring the response. What I am finding is that all the server threads become blocked/deadlocked after that. This seems like a really easy way to bring to server down and wanted to understand what is going on here.

Code from client is:

```
(require '[org.httpkit.client :as hk-client])

 (defn hget [id]
   (hk-client/get (str "http://localhost:5000/v1/pubapis/auth/ping?ping=" id)))

(doall (map hget (take 100 (range))))) ; Gives problem
(doall (map deref (map hget (take 100 (range)))))) ; Doesn't give problem
```

[image: Thread status]
Threads blocked at

sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:118)

and deadlocked at

java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:479)

Would really appreciate if someone can help with what is going on over here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found what the problem was. Took lot of digging through and starting with a sample project to find this.
When I started learning clojure and copied the following from somewhere for logging:

```
(defn log [msg & vals]
  (let [line (apply format msg vals)]
    (locking System/out (println line))))
```

The line locking over there was causing dead lock in some situation. Do not know enough about concurrency to solve this. Will create a separate question for that.

Removing this line fixes the problem.

Comment: The blocking on those lines indicates that your client isn't reading from the socket.  The server has entered into that thread blocking on a congested connection (something to write, nothing is reading).  When you say "but ignoring the response", I hope that you read the response, or terminate the connection.

Comment: This code is getting executed on server. And a line in middleware is calling log. Client is making an http request and ignoring the response, which means that as per https://github.com/http-kit/http-kit/issues/66#issuecomment-22441928 it will get on client "response received, decoded and throw away, get garbage collectioned".